# Is there a measure other than variance to know dispersion?

Tags: distributions, python, variance

I have (x,y) values where x are integers that range from 0 to 843, and there is only one y value per x value.

And then I have a set S, which are (x,y) values. If an element of S is selected, it should add up to the y value of the corresponding x in the above (x, y) values.

I want to select a subset of S, that would make the sum of all y values close to N while having the y values distributed flat (i.e., (x,y) graph looking as if it is a straight vertical line if seen in a bigger scale).

I tried with variance, having variance biggest as possible, but it would also make only the y values of the beginning and end big.

So I wonder if there's any other measure to use or whether I should add any other metrics to achieve my goal along with variance. Thank you!

Comment: Is the number of selected elements fixed? Or are you happy with any number as long as the sum of the $y$ is close to $N$ and the distribution of $y$ "flat"? A problem here is that "flatness" may be hard to compare between different numbers of elements. If you select just one element with $y=N$, is this flat or not? Also, "flatness" may depend on whether the $x$ are distributed more or less uniformly (for example there could be lots of $x$ on the left side and a lonely one far on the right side).

Comment: @ChristianHennig I want it to be flat in that if seen in a bird eyes' view when drawn a line between the x,y values it will be something without any peak. Ideally, all the values to be y=N/843
Also, the number of selected elements is not fixed

Comment: If you want all the values of $y$ approximately equal, you want *low* variance, not high.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Oh I tried with weighted variance while having the x values as weight, instead of calculating the variance of the occurrence of y.

Comment: It is not altogether clare what you want, but it looks like a measure of ûniformity^is what you need, not dispersion. Entropy is one such, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484406/how-to-measure-whether-a-discrete-distribution-is-uniform-or-not  and search this site!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen wow thank you so much!! I think entropy is one of the measure I can use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal by using entropy. Since I want the distribution to be seen uniformly on a larger scale, I used binning and then calculated the entropy. I used this approach with multiple bin sizes together.